# Android-Like keyboard with HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, keyboard

Having problems about  a Virtual Keyboard in my website (its Touchable) , and I wish to have an Android-Like keyboard behavior.

My major problem is ... **screen focus**.

I can display a simple keyboard (plugin or handmake) on the screen but I cannot achieve the focus effect over a control when I display it.

All the plugins I found in the web only display a keyboard on the screen ... **but** ... how can I have that **and also** ... focus an inputbox (i.e) correctly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 : In order to better explain what I mean... Check your android phone, go to any Form inside it ... some with a couple of textboxes.
Click on anyone ... you can see that the virtualkeyboard appears taking some screen zone, and the textbox goes up so you can see what you type ? Thats what I mean.

So Not Only ordinary Focus ... also ... to have the inputbox visible while  a virtualkeyboard appears in the screen .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain focus on an input tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670277/maintain-focus-on-an-input-tag)

Comment: Already edited to better explain the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, I see. The only solution I found online (I never tried creating a virtual keyboard) is to dynamically set the input's position to fixed when focused and set it back to relative onblur. here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951154/scrolling-to-selected-element-while-typing-on-iphone-safari-virtual-keyboard